# How to return a "Tuple type" in a UDF in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

All the [data types in `pyspark.sql.types` are](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html):

```
__all__ = [
    "DataType", "NullType", "StringType", "BinaryType", "BooleanType", "DateType",
    "TimestampType", "DecimalType", "DoubleType", "FloatType", "ByteType", "IntegerType",
    "LongType", "ShortType", "ArrayType", "MapType", "StructField", "StructType"]
```

I have to write a UDF (in pyspark) which returns an array of tuples. What do I give the second argument to it which is the return type of the udf method? It would be something on the lines of `ArrayType(TupleType())`...

Comment: Your title question doesn't appear to match the body. Doesn't the documentation tell you how to set a return value to be *"container type of other type"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have changed the title. Hopefully it's representative of the body now.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no such thing as a `TupleType` in Spark. Product types are represented as `structs` with fields of specific type. For example if you want to return an array of pairs (integer, string) you can use schema like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("char", StringType(), False),
    StructField("count", IntegerType(), False)
]))
```

Example usage:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from collections import Counter

char_count_udf = udf(
    lambda s: Counter(s).most_common(),
    schema
)

df = sc.parallelize([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")]).toDF(["id", "value"])

df.select("*", char_count_udf(df["value"])).show(2, False)

## +---+-----+-------------------------+
## |id |value|PythonUDF#<lambda>(value)|
## +---+-----+-------------------------+
## |1  |foo  |[[o,2], [f,1]]           |
## |2  |bar  |[[r,1], [a,1], [b,1]]    |
## +---+-----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer is working, but my case is a bit complex. My return data is of the type `[('a1', [('b1', 1), ('b2', 2)]), ('a2', [('b1', 1), ('b2', 2)])]` and so I make a type as `ArrayType(StructType([StructField("date", StringType(), False), ArrayType(StructType([StructField("hashId", StringType(), False), StructField("TimeSpent-Front", FloatType(), False), StructField("TimeSpent-Back", FloatType(), False)]))]))` which gives **'ArrayType' object has no attribute 'name'**...

Comment: `StructType` requires an sequence of `StructFields` hence you cannot use `ArrayTypes` alone. You need `StructField` which stores `ArrayType`. Also word of advice - if you find yourself creating structures like this you should probably rethink data model. Deeply nested structures are hard to handle without UDFs and Python UDFs are far from efficient.

Comment: How can I just specify schema in udf to return a list . F.udf(lambda start_date, end_date : [0,1] if  start_date < end_date else  [1]).

Comment: This `ArrayType(StructType([Structfield("col1", StringType(), False), StructField("col2",FloatType()), False)]))` is giving me an error: 

`TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ArrayType(StructType(List(StructField(langid,StringType,false),StructField(probability,FloatType,false))),true) of type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.` (in pyspark 3.2.1)

Answer (score 22):

Stackoverflow keeps directing me to this question, so I guess I'll add some info here.

Returning simple types from UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def get_df():
  d = [(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 3.0), (1.0, 6.0), (1.0, 9.0)]
  df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(d, ['x', 'y'])
  return df

df = get_df()
df.show()

# +---+---+
# |  x|  y|
# +---+---+
# |0.0|0.0|
# |0.0|3.0|
# |1.0|6.0|
# |1.0|9.0|
# +---+---+

func = udf(lambda x: str(x), StringType())
df = df.withColumn('y_str', func('y'))

func = udf(lambda x: int(x), IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('y_int', func('y'))

df.show()

# +---+---+-----+-----+
# |  x|  y|y_str|y_int|
# +---+---+-----+-----+
# |0.0|0.0|  0.0|    0|
# |0.0|3.0|  3.0|    3|
# |1.0|6.0|  6.0|    6|
# |1.0|9.0|  9.0|    9|
# +---+---+-----+-----+

df.printSchema()

# root
#  |-- x: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- y: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- y_str: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- y_int: integer (nullable = true)
```

When integers are not enough:

```
df = get_df()

func = udf(lambda x: [0]*int(x), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn('list', func('y'))

func = udf(lambda x: {float(y): str(y) for y in range(int(x))}, 
           MapType(FloatType(), StringType()))
df = df.withColumn('map', func('y'))

df.show()
# +---+---+--------------------+--------------------+
# |  x|  y|                list|                 map|
# +---+---+--------------------+--------------------+
# |0.0|0.0|                  []|               Map()|
# |0.0|3.0|           [0, 0, 0]|Map(2.0 -> 2, 0.0...|
# |1.0|6.0|  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|Map(0.0 -> 0, 5.0...|
# |1.0|9.0|[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...|Map(0.0 -> 0, 5.0...|
# +---+---+--------------------+--------------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- x: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- y: double (nullable = true)
#  |-- list: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
#  |-- map: map (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- key: float
#  |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

Returning complex datatypes from UDF:

```
df = get_df()
df = df.groupBy('x').agg(F.collect_list('y').alias('y[]'))
df.show()

# +---+----------+
# |  x|       y[]|
# +---+----------+
# |0.0|[0.0, 3.0]|
# |1.0|[9.0, 6.0]|
# +---+----------+

schema = StructType([
    StructField("min", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("size", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("edges",  ArrayType(FloatType()), True),
    StructField("val_to_index",  MapType(FloatType(), IntegerType()), True)
    # StructField('insanity', StructType([StructField("min_", FloatType(), True), StructField("size_", IntegerType(), True)]))

])

def func(values):
  mn = min(values)
  size = len(values)
  lst = sorted(values)[::-1]
  val_to_index = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(values)}
  return (mn, size, lst, val_to_index)

func = udf(func, schema)
dff = df.select('*', func('y[]').alias('complex_type'))
dff.show(10, False)

# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
# |x  |y[]       |complex_type                                          |
# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
# |0.0|[0.0, 3.0]|[0.0,2,WrappedArray(3.0, 0.0),Map(0.0 -> 0, 3.0 -> 1)]|
# |1.0|[6.0, 9.0]|[6.0,2,WrappedArray(9.0, 6.0),Map(9.0 -> 1, 6.0 -> 0)]|
# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+

dff.printSchema()

# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
# |x  |y[]       |complex_type                                          |
# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
# |0.0|[0.0, 3.0]|[0.0,2,WrappedArray(3.0, 0.0),Map(0.0 -> 0, 3.0 -> 1)]|
# |1.0|[6.0, 9.0]|[6.0,2,WrappedArray(9.0, 6.0),Map(9.0 -> 1, 6.0 -> 0)]|
# +---+----------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Passing multiple arguments to a UDF:

```
df = get_df()
func = udf(lambda arr: arr[0]*arr[1],FloatType())
df = df.withColumn('x*y', func(F.array('x', 'y')))

    # +---+---+---+
    # |  x|  y|x*y|
    # +---+---+---+
    # |0.0|0.0|0.0|
    # |0.0|3.0|0.0|
    # |1.0|6.0|6.0|
    # |1.0|9.0|9.0|
    # +---+---+---+
```

The code is purely for demo purposes, all above transformation are available in Spark code and would yield much better performance.
As @zero323 in the comment above, UDFs should generally be avoided in pyspark; returning complex types should make you think about simplifying your logic.

Answer (score 1):

For the scala version instead of python.
version 2.4

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val testschema : StructType = StructType(
    StructField("number", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("Array",  ArrayType(StructType(StructField("cnt_rnk", IntegerType) :: StructField("comp", StringType) :: Nil))) :: 
    StructField("comp", StringType):: Nil)
```

The tree structure looks like this.

```
testschema.printTreeString
root
 |-- number: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- cnt_rnk: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- corp_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- comp: string (nullable = true)
```