# Formatting string representation of structure to python dictionary

Tags: python, pyspark

I need a little help processing a String to a Dict, considering that the String is not in a common format, but an output from a UDF function

The return from the PySpark UDF looks like the string below:

```
"{list=[{a=1}, {a=2}, {a=3}]}"
```

And I need to convert it to a python dictionary with the structure below:

```
{
  "list": [
    {"a": 1}
    {"a": 2}
    {"a": 3}
  ]
}
```

So I can access it's values, like

```
dict["list"][1]["a"]
```

I already tried using:

- JSON.loads
- ast_eval()

Could someone please help me?

As an example of how this unparsed string is generated:

```
@udf()
def execute_method():
  return {"list": [{"a":1},{"b":1}{"c":1}]}

df_result = df_source.withColumn("result", execute_method())
```

Comment: I don't think `{list=[{a=1}, {a=2}, {a=3}]}` is JSON. `{list: [{a: 1}, {a: 2}, {a: 3}]}` would be

Comment: Try `<original string name>.replace("=", ": ")`. It will replace all occurrences of an equal sign with a colon.

Comment: It isn't, that's exactly the point. It's a string representation from a struct

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. This is definitely parsable, but you should show the code that is returning this instead, as there is probably a way to get a format that is useful to you

Comment: @Cireo updated the question with an example of the code returning this unparsed string

Comment: Might be able to provide a schema for your return then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841721/2284490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very least you will need to replace `=` with `:` and surround keys with double quotes:

```
import json
import re

string = "{list=[{a=1}, {a=2}, {a=3}]}"
fixed_string = re.sub(r'(\w+)=', r'"\1":', string)
print(type(fixed_string), fixed_string)
parsed = json.loads(fixed_string)
print(type(parsed), parsed)
```

outputs

```
<class 'str'> {"list":[{"a":1}, {"a":2}, {"a":3}]}
<class 'dict'> {'list': [{'a': 1}, {'a': 2}, {'a': 3}]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately `literal_eval` doesn't allow `dict`, but you can do `eval(raw.replace('{', 'dict(').replace('}', ')'))` as well

Comment: @Cireo, no, never use `eval` when there is a safer option. Also, I'm pretty sure `'list'` is just an arbitrary key name, not the `list` type. Either way, there is a better way than using `eval`

Comment: @DeepSpace it is indeed just an arbitrary key

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import re
import json  
data="{list=[{a=1}, {a=2}, {a=3}]}"
data=data.replace('=',':')
pattern=[e.group() for e in re.finditer('[a-z]+', data, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
for e in set(pattern):
    data=data.replace(e,"\""+e+"\"")
print(json.loads(data))
```