# How can I avoid Pandas dataframe in Spark pipeline?

Tags: python, apache-spark, parsing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm a newbie in PySpark, and I want to parse data as below:

```py
#                   http_path
#0  https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#frag...
#1  https://example.org/path/to/file

#                 A                                 B
#0  https://example.org/path/to/file         param=42#fragment
#1  https://example.org/path/to/file                NaN
```

Below is the example:

| data | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment | path/to/file | param=42#fragment |
| https://example.org/path/to/file | path/to/file | NaN |

**Problem:** what is the best approach to parsing data *without* converting Spark dataframe to Pandas datafarame `toPandas()` to optimize the pipeline and process it 100% spark form?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to implement a UDF. Please show your Spark code that starts with your initial datafile

Comment: So, starting with the first pandas usage, instead of `pd.concat([sdf.toPandas()['raw']`, have you tried using sparks withColumn function?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I couldn't manage it for concatenation, but I'm sure that there is a way to do it in Spark.. If we want to review it from the beginning, even for splitting I couldn't adapt `regex = r'([^\?]+)\?*(.*)'`  and I used finally `split('?')`. Even regarding resetting the index I had to use `sdf.toPandas().reset_index()` I couldn't manage it in spark. If you could translate them apart from FE step, It would be extra learning value for sure.

Comment: Overall, I would advise not splitting, resetting, etc. Instead create a UDF function that parses a whole URI (your first column) and returns a Struct type that includes authority, schema, path, fragment, and query parameters (as a list). From there you can optionally flatten or use other UDF functions on the entire Struct column to build the numeric feature columns

Comment: @OneCricketeer Sound's really promising if it could provide me with the final *expected output* in form of a Spark dataframe so that I can include the rest of the ML-based components.

Comment: I don't have a Spark environment setup, but you can start here https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html +https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841721/2308683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you can use [`urllib.parse`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) module to parse URLs. Don't do splitting and manual extraction. With that, [wrap it in a UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841721/2308683) to create a nested Struct that you can access attributes on.

For example,

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.master("local")
    .appName("urlParse")
    .config("spark.ui.port", "4050")
    .getOrCreate()
)
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        Row(http_path="https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment"),
        Row(http_path="https://example.org/path/to/file"),
    ]
)

# ---

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("path", StringType(), False),
        StructField("query", ArrayType(StringType(), False), True),
        StructField("fragment", StringType(), True),
    ]
)


def _parse_url(s):
    data = urlsplit(s)
    if data[3]:
        query_params = list()
        query_params.append(data[3])
    else:
        query_params = None
    return {
        "path": "{}://{}/{}".format(data[0], data[1].rstrip("/"), data[2]),
        "query": query_params,
        "fragment": data[4],
    }


url_parse_udf = f.udf(_parse_url, schema)

parsed = sdf.select("*", url_parse_udf(sdf["http_path"]).alias("data"))
```

From there, define more UDFs to do your feature extraction, and pass them through to a select function or use `withColumn` to "concat"

---

#### Sample output

```
parsed.printSchema()
parsed.show(truncate=False)

parsed.select("data.*").show()
parsed.select(f.explode("data.query")).show()  # show that nulls are dropped
```

```
root
 |-- http_path: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- path: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- query: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- fragment: string (nullable = true)

+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|http_path                                         |data                                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|https://example.org/path/to/file?param=42#fragment|{https://example.org//path/to/file, [param=42], fragment}|
|https://example.org/path/to/file                  |{https://example.org//path/to/file, null, }              |
+--------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+

+--------------------+----------+--------+
|                path|     query|fragment|
+--------------------+----------+--------+
|https://example.o...|[param=42]|fragment|
|https://example.o...|      null|        |
+--------------------+----------+--------+

+--------+
|     col|
+--------+
|param=42|
+--------+
```