# Modify Different Pyspark Column on Exception in UDF

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a data frame and a function that I want to run on every cell in my data frame:

```
def foo(x):
    # does stuff to x
    return x

foo_udf = udf(lambda x: foo(x), StringType())
df = df.withColumn("col1", foo_udf(col("col1")))
.withColumn("col2", foo_udf(col("col2")))
.withColumn("col3", foo_udf(col("col3")))
```

It simply modifies the data passed in and returns a new value to replace the passed in value.

However, there may be instances where an error will occur, for these instances, I have another column `col4` which will store a boolean of whether or not the udf failed for that row.

My issue is that when this occurs, I have no way of accessing `col4` for that given row.

Comment: does it not throw an exception and stop the execution? if not, what happens to the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this on a partition level with mapPartition. I will use [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue/) which will provide an easier interface to bring this to Spark.

First some setup:

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any, Iterable
import pandas as pd

def foo(x):
    if x == "E":
        raise ValueError()
    return x + "_ran"

def logic(df: List[Dict[str,Any]]) -> List[Dict[str,Any]]:
    for row in df:
        try:
            x = foo(row["col1"])
            y = foo(row["col2"])
            z = foo(row["col3"])
            # if it reaches here, we can update all
            row["col1"] = x
            row["col2"] = y
            row["col3"] = z
            row["col4"] = False
        except:
            row["col4"] = True
    return df
```

`foo()` is your original function and `logic()` is a wrapper to only update the columns if every `foo()` call is successful. Annotating the function will guide Fugue to apply conversions. From here we can use Fugue's `transform()` to test on Pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "B", "C"], "col2": ["A", "B", "C"], "col3": ["D", "E", "F"]})

from fugue import transform
transform(df, logic, schema="*, col4:boolean")
```

The schema is a requirement for Spark operations. This is just a minimal expression and then Fugue handles it, and then we get a result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A_ran   A_ran   D_ran   False
B       B       E       True
C_ran   C_ran   F_ran   False
```

so we can bring it to Spark. We just need to supply a SparkSession.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
transform(sdf, logic, schema="*, col4:boolean", engine=spark).show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without fugue?

Comment: It will be a lot more code, but in general you want mapPartitions, not a UDF. Like this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-mappartitions/ . But Fugue pushes down to this and removes boilerplate.

Comment: Or if you change the logic to handle Pandas DataFrames, you can try mapInPandas, but then that will require 2 helper functions to be written also. See this: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.mapInPandas

Comment: Is there also a way to run this in parallel? It seems to be very slow when I run it.

Comment: This should already run in parallel on the Spark level so you can't parallelize the logic. It may be slow because of the for-loop. If you can express the logic in Pandas and numpy, the logic function may be re-written to utilize Pandas vectorization. I don't think this kind of logic can be vectorized because Pandas apply is also slow. It also depends on foo. I think you can try making more partitions on the Spark DataFrame input if you have more workers that you can take advantage of. Maybe the problem can also be thought of in a different way? The current setup seems to be slow in nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can only return/change a single column from an UDF. However, this column can be a [StructType](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841721/2129801), containing the payload and an error flag. Then you can "unpack" the struct column into two (or more) normal columns.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

#some testdata
data = [['A', 4],
    ['B', 2],
    ['C', 5]]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "col1"])

#the udf
def foo(x):
    if x == 5:
        error=True
    else:
        error=False
    return [x, error]

foo_udf = F.udf(lambda x: foo(x), returnType = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("x", T.StringType(), False),
    T.StructField("error", T.BooleanType(), False)
]))

#calling the udf and unpacking the return values
df.withColumn("col1", foo_udf("col1")) \
    .withColumn("error", F.col("col1.error")) \
    .withColumn("col1", F.col("col1.x")) \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-----+
| id|col1|error|
+---+----+-----+
|  A|   4|false|
|  B|   2|false|
|  C|   5| true|
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: This is promising, but it won't work for cases where say col1 has an error, but col2 is fine, col2.error will overwrite the error column.

Comment: You don't have to name the error column `error`, you can simply use names like `error1`, `error2`, ... After you have finished calling the udfs, you can combine all error columns either with `or` or `and`, depending on your requirements

Comment: Would creating all these temporary error columns have an impact on performance?

Comment: I don't think so. Just check the physical plan with [explain](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain.html). These temp columns won't introduce any additional shuffles. The main performance bottleneck will be the udf calls anyway (udfs tend to be slow compared with native Spark transformations).

Comment: This ended up dropping performance by about 4x