# Add error handling decorator in addition to pandas_udf

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, python-decorators

I'd like to create a decorator that handles errors inside of a `pandas_udf`. I've tried a few attempts with no luck so wanted to see if anyone has been successful in doing this?

Below is some initial code I've tried but it fails. In this example, I'm trying to decorate the function `pandas_divide` with both `pandas_udf` and a new decorator to detect errors, `return_code`.

I'm not sure if my idea is possible given the fact that pandas UDFs require us to define a single return data type (whereas this idea of wrapping it in a safe call would allow for either the output of the function to be returned in the column or an exception). I tried researching if I could define a new pyspark data type that is the union of one data type, an exception and None but did not have any luck - is this possible?

I was also thinking of using a closure to try and get this functionality but closures are new to me so I'm still looking into this.

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

# create dataframe for testing
df = spark.range(0, 10).withColumn('id', (F.col('id') / 10).cast('integer')).withColumn('v', F.rand())
columns = ['id', 'v']
vals = [(1, 2), (2, 0), (3, 0)]
new_rows_df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df = df.union(new_rows_df)
df.cache()
df.count()
display(df)

class ReturnCode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pass1 = 'PASS'
        self.fail1 = 'FAIL'
    
    def __call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        def inner_func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                output = func(**kwargs)
                return_code = self.pass1
            except Exception as ex:
                output = f"{ex}"
                return_code = self.fail1
            return (return_code, output)
        return inner_func

return_code = ReturnCode()

@pandas_udf(T.StructType(T.StructField('return_code', T.StringType()), T.StructField('value', T.IntegerType())))
@return_code
def pandas_divide(v):
    if v == 0:
        raise
    return 1/v

#pandas_divide(0)[0]
df = df.withColumn('pandas_divide', pandas_divide(F.col('v')))
df.show()
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible either because it's expecting a DataFrame back with explicit schema. What is the goal here? I think you will get an error with the bad input right? I suspect the goal is to make debugging easier because Spark tracebacks are so long?

Comment: @KevinKho yeah, the goal is to help with debugging and also just to make it so if say 1% of records have an issue, the whole process doesn't just fail. I'd love to filter those "bad" records out after the fact if that makes sense.

Comment: I think you can create a UDF to keep the error like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493429/modify-different-pyspark-column-on-exception-in-udf/73495564?noredirect=1#comment130081337_73495564